# Table header not aligned with table rows called by ajax

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tdqfx.png)I have used an ajax call to retrieve data for rows. My result does not show proper formatting of the table. The rows appear within the first column of the header. I had added the table header within the body, so I'm not sure if it's because of that or not.

Please help me in making the header and rows aligned. Thanks in advance.

Here's my piece of code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.ajax({
    url: "/otcs/livelink.exe/open/WebReport1",
    dataType: 'html',
    async: true,
    success: function(result) {
      var $response = $(result);
      // console.log(result)
      var a = $(result).find("tr.GO").clone();
      $("#div1").html(a);
    }
  });
});

function Display1() {
  $("#TableHeading1").toggle();
  $("#div1").toggle();
}
```

```css
table.Table {
  align: center;
  margin-right: 50px;
  font-family: calibri;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

#TableHeading1>th {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  font-family: times new roman;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-style: double;
}

.GO>td {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="hide" style="display:none"></div>

<button type="button" style="font-family:calibri;font-size:25px;background-color:Teal;color:white;width:150px;height:50px;cursor:pointer;" onclick="Display1();">GO</button>

<div>
  <table class="Table">
    <tr id="TableHeading1" style="display:none">
      <th>Employee ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Mail address</th>
      <th>Phone Number</th>
      <th>Designation</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="div1" style="display:none"></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I've converted your code to a snippet, but it's not much use as a) it makes an ajax call and b) there's no indication of the results of that ajax call or what .GO might be.  Can you include an example of the ajax result?

Comment: One issue might be that you're doing `$("tr.GO").clone()` then inserting that inside another `tr` - ie nesting the tr's.    Your `$("#div1").html(a);` will only work if `a` is the content of a single row, eg `<td>col1></td><td>col2</td>` which it isn't as it's a clone of a `tr`

Comment: You can't nest a `tr` directly inside a `tr`.  Quickest fix, depending on your actual requirements, would be to change `$("#div1").html(a)` to `$("#div1").closest("body").html(a)` (but then you lose #div1) *or* `var a = $(result).find("tr.GO").clone()` to `var a = $(result).find("tr.GO").clone().html()` or add an id to the table then `$("#tableId > tbody").append(a)` - but it's not clear from requirements if you want to replace or append the table

Comment: Giving var a = $(result).find("tr.GO").clone().html() fetches only the first row and the rest is not being displayed

Comment: No idea what you mean by "fetches on the first row" - that's bit of code is single line to ... fetch the first row ... you need to do something with it, like append it to the table's tbody.